# Read (repair) data from broken floppy disc on a linux system

Tags: linux, file-recovery, floppy, forensics

How can I read an old floppy disk under Linux that has some problematic sectors?
In times of `DOS` people used magic tools like `Norton Disk Doctor` and others.

Some of these tools read the broken part many times until they had success. Others used more intelligence. As far I remember some of these tools could repair nearly every broken file after some time.

I tried `dd if=/dev/fd0 of=001.img` but it stops with an error message
[dd_rescue](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/ddrescue) continues the job, but the image is not readable afterwards.

How can I recover the files from a very old floppy with Linux tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary for the other readers

Thanks to @ChrisF and @week it worked very well in the following order:

```
dd_rescue /dev/fd0 data.img
testdisk data.img
```

I could restore even deleted files. Screenshots can be found here [cgsecurity.org](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT)
Finally I found another tool called (gnu)`ddrescue` and a [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211578/whats-the-difference-between-ddrescue-gddrescue-and-dd-rescue) about the differences.

Answer (score 1):

`testdisk` should help with this. It's an opensource multiplatform data recovery software.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to *why* this will help.

Comment: testdisk has a nice menu and looks promising, but it was not very intelligent in reading.
testdisk and dd_rescue should create an image. The size of both images was the same. `testdisk ` was faster, but inserted 00 for 30% of the image, while dd_rescue wrote some data.

Comment: Add image created by dd_rescue as parameter to testdisk.

Comment: @week i guess that will be the best combination of both tools. I will try that. It is a pitty, that testdisk does not use the dd_rescue per option.

Comment: @JonasStein Wish you luck..

Comment: testdisk is for recovering damaged hard disk partition tables or reformatted filesystems.  It isn't going to help recover files on a damaged floppy.